# Rails 7: How can you call a class from outside the current namespace that is inside a different namespace?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a controller that is inside a namespace.

```
class Usecase::TestController < ApplicationController

 def create
   var = Posts::AnotherClass.new
 end
end
```

This other class is inside

```
app/domain/command/posts
```

And i have added in my Application.rb

```
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('app/domain/**/')
```

To make the command and other directories inside the domain directory part of the root.

The problema that im having is that when i try to call Post::AnotherClass from inside the controller it doesn't find it and the error i get is.

```
uninitialized constant Usecase::TestController::Posts
```

As if it was looking inside the TestController or the UseCase namespace. But if i put it like `::Posts::AnotherClass` the error is that `::Post` is not found.

What im doing wrong? I know that if its in the main namespace you use the `::` but i can't find how to call from a namespace a class inside another namespace.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the application.rb config that I had.

I was missing a Namespace `Command::Posts::AnotherClass`

So what i saw is that:

```
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('app/domain/**/')
```

Not joining to root all the directories inside domain.

To solve my problem I had to add this line and one for every directory inside domain:

```
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('app/domain/command/')
```